# How to set column's cell value depending on changes in other column?

Tags: gwt, cell, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have 3 column + 10 rows in celltable.
value1Column, value2Column, RecordState

1 | 2 | *

2 | 4 | -

:

9 | 5 | -

10| 5 | *

Whenever user changes values either value1 or value2 then immediately cell related to that record set to * in RecordState column.

How to set * in RecordState column on  value changes?

How to use setFieldUpdater to update values in column ?

value1Column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater() {
            public void update(int index,
                    RecordVO object, integer value) {
//How to set * in RecordState column ?
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to redraw the table to update the other column. So in the field updater for `value1Column` you would call something like RecordVO.valueUpdated() and then call `CellTable.redraw()`. Your column for the RecordState table should check if RecordVO.isUpdated() and output a value accordingly.